# Toggling a bool value is being flagged in the Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, boolean-expression

Take this simple code:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnOptionsAddTimeToConcludingComments()
{
    BOOL bAddTime = CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::AddRemainingTimeToConcludingComments();
    bAddTime = !bAddTime;
    CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::SetAddRemainingTimeToConcludingComments(bAddTime);

    UpdateMenuGUI();
    SetModified(true);
}
```

The `!bAddTime` is being flagged:

[image]

It says:

> Using logical '!' when bitwise '~' was probably intended.

I have used this technique before to toggle boolean values it appears to operate correctly. So why the warning? It is not related to Visual Assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change

```cpp
BOOL bAddTime = ...
```

to

```cpp
bool bAddTime = ...
```

I guess the static code analysis gets confused by `BOOL` being a type alias for `int`.